# how does mktemp make temporary files in a directory without write permissions in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I noticed that in ubuntu, mktemp allows a user to make temporary files in a directory even if write permissions are not allowed for that user. I thus expected the permissions on mktemp to read something like this, giving the user temporary root privileges while running it:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root   35392 Nov 19  2012 mktemp
```

but instead they read something like this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   35392 Nov 19  2012 mktemp
```

Where I thought there was an 's', there is an 'x', meaning mktemp does not run with root privileges. How is mktemp able to create temporary files in a directory without having the permission to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mktemp`, by default, creates a temporary directory under `/tmp`, which by default is writable by anyone; if you pass the `--tmpdir` option to `mktemp` (or set the `TMPDIR` environment variable), it will attempt to create a temporary directory in the directory given by the option's argument, and that *will* fail unless you have write permission in the given directory. For example:

```
[me@box] $ mktemp
/tmp/tmp.sL1g7rRGQv
[me@box] $ mktemp --tmpdir=/root
mktemp: failed to create file via template `/tmp.XXXXXXXXXXX': Permission denied
```

If you're doing, e.g., `mktemp --tmpdir=/root` as a non-root user and it *doesn't* fail, then something very weird is going on. Are you sure that's what you're seeing?

Comment: I was just using default flags. I thought it put files into ./tmp , not /tmp because I apparently wasn't paying attention. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: A little nit-picking: IMHO `/tmp` has usually the _sticky bit_ (`t`) set: `drwxrwxrwt root root 0 May 24 23:52 /tmp`. I. e. everybody can create files/dirs in it, but cannot delete/rename files owned by someone else -- even it is _formally_ world writable as indicated by `ls`. For more info see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit